# What will be the difference in values after fork calls for child and parent process?

Tags: c, fork, system-calls

I am not able to figure how it works.The fork system call splits the parent into two process ,it returns zero for the child process .According to me output should be glb=101.var=89 for child process .But I am wrong .Can someone please explain how its working ?

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int glb=100;
int main()
{
    int pid;  
    int var =88;
    printf ("Before Fork\n");
    pid=fork();
    if(pid <0)
    {
        perror("fork");
        exit(1);
    }
    if(pid ==0) /**child**/
    {
        glb++;var++;
    }
    else 
    {
        sleep(5);
    }

    printf("pid= %d,glb=%d,var=%d\n",getpid(),glb,var);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Works fine for me:  `Before Fork`
`pid= 31955,glb=101,var=89`
`pid= 31954,glb=100,var=88`  What output are you getting that suggests it doesn't?

Comment: You're wrong about the child not outputting "glb=101,var=89"?  It does output that.

Comment: Yeah now it does,I closed the terminal and ran it again now it works fine.I have one question though,are they pids in increasing order or can they vary also.Thanks .

Comment: pids are vaguely increasing on windows and linux, but they are re-used, so no real guarantees about the reuse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When process forks, its address space is being cloned, so there would be a single segment with stack of main thread (where `var` is located) but two processes referencing it:

```
            +-------+
parent ---> |  var  | <--- child
            +-------+
```

Same works for data segments where `glb` is located.

When any of them attempts to modify it, a *copy-on-write page fault* is generated and data segment is being copied by operating system:

```
            +--------+  var++
parent ---> |   88   | <--- child
            +--------+

Handle cow-fault:

            +--------+             +--------+
parent ---> |   88   |  child ---> |   88   |
            +--------+             +--------+

Restart from same instruction:

            +--------+        var++ +--------+
parent ---> |   88   |  child ----> |   88   |
            +--------+              +--------+

            +--------+       printf +--------+
parent ---> |   88   |  child ----> |   89   |
            +--------+              +--------+
```

So child should print 101 and 89, while parent should print 100 and 88.